# Dog not taking a house move well

Tags: dogs, house-moving

We have 2 female working GSDs. We have moved house in the last 2 days and one of our GSDs has been fine with it, the other however isn’t taking it well.

She now has to stay downstairs now where as before she used to sleep upstairs. She whines and cries at the bottom of the stairs until late and starts again early.

I know this is completely new, new house, new smells, new surroundings but this has to be the worst she’s been in any house move we’ve had. She seems at her most comfortable when in the garden or when we go for a walk.

Is there anything we can to help her settle?

Comment: Can you please explain why she has to stay downstairs? Is your bedroom upstairs and she wants to sleep in the same room as you?

Comment: The landlady doesn’t want dogs upstairs on the new carpets. Our bedroom is upstairs. Her routine was that she’d come upstairs for 30 mins then she’d take herself off and sleep where she wanted to (landing or downstairs)

Comment: So the actual problem might not be the change in location, but that she cannot be with you in the evening. I heard of several pets (cats and dogs) that want to make sure their humans are alright every night before going to sleep.

Comment: Potentially. She has started to settle the past few nights since posting which is nice to see

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP indicated that it's no longer relevant and therefore cannot be answered in any meaningful way.